# CSS: Target a container with items overflown (is showing a scrollbar)

Tags: css, flexbox

So I want to have carousel like functionality where I have a container (absolute, full width) and inside a list of cards (fixed width each).

I want the cards to be positioned in the middle of the container (so container is flex and justify-content: center).

[image]

All works fine while I have few cards

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #bbb;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  gap: 8px;
}

.container .card{
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">card 1</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div>
  <div class="card">card 3</div>
</div>
```

But as soon as I get more cards that overflows the container (full width, overflow-x: auto)... I get the scrollbar. Which is exactly what I wanted... the only and big issue is, the scrollbar does not go left far enough... or in other words... first card(s) get cut... since the flex's content is centered...

[image]

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #bbb;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  gap: 8px;
}

.container .card{
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">card 1</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div>
  <div class="card">card 3</div>
  <div class="card">card 4</div>
  <div class="card">card 5</div>
  <div class="card">card 6</div>
  <div class="card">card 7</div>
  <div class="card">card 8</div>
  <div class="card">card 9</div>
  <div class="card">card 10</div>
  <div class="card">card 11</div>
  <div class="card">card 12</div>
</div>
```

What I would like, the container's default functionality to be flex / justify-content: center, but when cards start to overflow to go to justify-content: left...

can this be done without JS?

Comment: Do you have any sample markup yet? If so, please provide an executable snippet.

Comment: added the snippets

Comment: margin-left: auto to the first child and margin-right: auto to the last child

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be done... the best solution I could do was to add another wrapper around the cards and have it positioned center (margin-left / right: auto) and **width: fit-content**; display: flex; justify-content: start;

and remove the flex box on the .container

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #bbb;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.container .cards{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 8px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: fit-content;

}

.container .card{
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">card 1</div>
    <div class="card">card 2</div>
    <div class="card">card 3</div>
    <div class="card">card 4</div>
    <div class="card">card 5</div>
    <div class="card">card 6</div>
    <div class="card">card 7</div>
    <div class="card">card 8</div>
    <div class="card">card 9</div>
    <div class="card">card 10</div>
    <div class="card">card 11</div>
    <div class="card">card 12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be a reasonable approach. The problem with flex is that it tries to make the items fit on itself (shrink/grow). If you set it to have a specific size, it limits the ability of flexbox to make it fit. When you have too many cards, the container is just not wide enough to contain all, so usually this is where flex-wrap comes into play. So the idea is to make the container bigger. Since you want the items to be centered use a wrapper like you did. Also, fit-content is probably the best option that you have here. If you set min-width: 0 on the initial snippet you will see what I mean

Comment: display: block on divs is redundant btw. unless you do something with css that overrides it.